# Remove Ubuntu's default applications

Tags: ubuntu

I need to remove everything I don't need in my OS, Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin), in order to have an smoother faster and better boot, remove things and packages like the printers manager and the Bluetooth, and all that takes time for it to response in a faster way.

Comment: better to do it from terminal and without the need to download anything

Comment: Not sure if your asking the right question; have you thought about a different debian based distro?  kubuntu, ubuntu server, or even DSL (damn small linux) might be a better fit.

Comment: I did but some of the features I need are on this particular distribution, and my team doesn't feel like changing the OS... since they already have everything they need in there, but they don't know how to remove the rest of the "useless tools" (the ones they want to remove)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something that can be useful, to remove what I was asking for, like the Bluetooth manager and the printer manager that doesn't show in the startup software screen or that I can't find where to deactivate or disable them.

It goes like this:

```
sudo sed --in-place 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g' StuffToRemove.desktop
```

For example:

```
sudo sed --in-place 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g'  bluetooth-applet.desktop
```

For this you get into `cd /etc/xdg/autostart/`, and there you can see what are in your computer and disable them with the command above.

I don't know why, but I can't see them in the startup software manager app or something that is in the desktop, and another solution I found, but quite "difficult" was to remove the eyecandy, but since it is hardcoded, you have to find where and how it is, modify it and compile it yourself.

But anyways thanks for your useful options. I tried the Unity 2D already, but it didn't seem to change or help enough.

Also, for the needs I used Ltib... it's not that easy but worth it. I would have changed to another OS, but I don't know any good ARM OS.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do that from Ubuntu Software Center. In installed packages remove what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think removing unneeded packages will achieve the speed-up you're expecting. If you're currently using Unity, try switching to Unity 2D or GNOME Classic (selected by clicking the Ubuntu icon in the login prompt). If you're already using one of those, try even simpler GUIs, like Xfce or LXDE.

You can install the latter two with these commands, respectively:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
sudo apt-get install lxde
```

That being said, if you open the *Software Center* (press <kbd>Super</kbd>, enter *soft*, and select **Ubuntu Software Center**) and click **Installed** in the menu bar, you get a list of all installed packages.

You can simply click **Show N technical items** in the status bar, browse through the list and uninstall them on a case-by-case basis or enter, e.g., *bluetooth* in the search box and click **Show N technical items** to find all installed packages related to Bluetooth.

Comment: @Scott: What makes `&downarrow;` incorrect?

Comment: It’s not standard (see http://text-symbols.com/html) and it doesn’t work in Internet Explorer (at least not IE8; see [this screen shot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bdYZB.png)).

Comment: @Scott: It appears in W3C's [Character Entity Reference Chart](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref), but I suppose lack of support in IE is reason enough not to use it anymore. *sigh*

Comment: Thanks for the link; I didn’t know about that one.  (Although I will use it with caution, now that I know that it includes codes that IE doesn’t recognize.)

Comment: For the record, IE9 behaves the same as IE8 –– it does not interpret `&downarrow;`.

Comment: its not only to make it run faster but to boot the PC a little bit faster.